# Why are SKSpriteNodes only partially rendering?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, rendering, skspritenode

I've coded a basic layout of "cards" for level selection in a game using Swift and SpriteKit. It's basically just 6 level selection cards side by side that have a picture of the level that the user can select. To create them I am running a for-loop and placing the first one in the center of the screen, a padding, then the second one, then padding etc. Each card is an SKSpriteNode from a png image. Each card is approx a 3rd of the device wide and about a 3rd of the devices height.

I create all six of them and then created an action that moves all 6 cards left or right to select which on the player would like. The one in the center is the one that is selected.

Everything works great on iphone simulators (tested on iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus, iPhone 7 Plus and iPhone 5... all work great). On iPad simulators the first and last card have a portion of the image that doesn't render at all. The first card has about 1/4 of it lost on the left side, the last card has about 1/4 or it lost on the far right side. I tried running it on a physical iPad as well and it has the same issue. When I run it on an iPad Pro 12.7 it gets worse... it cuts off more of the image.

If I choose only to display 5 of the 6 cards they all render great.

If I choose to shrink them down to about 1/4 of the device width and 1/4 of the device height and lessen the padding they render fine.

I tried playing with the Scene and View sizes and scales and didn't have any improvement.

I've tried using different images and there is no changes at all.

I've double checked all zPositions and found no improvement.

I've tried systematically removing all other objects in the scene and still have the problem.

I've put them on their own "layer" which is an SKEffectNode named cardNode. (it's an SKEffectNode because I choose to later blur it when an alert screen comes up in front of it). I thought that putting them onto their own layer might help but it didn't.

I've put physics bodies on the cards just to make sure that they are still "there" and the physics bodies appear in the correct places. If I click on part of the node that isn't rendered it still does behave properly as though it was still rendered in that area.

I can't figure out where to go from here to fix this. Ideally I would like to add more cards yet in the future but getting stuck on this problem.

Here is the code that I have for creating the cards.

```
let cardNode = SKEffectNode()

let levelCardArray: [String] = [
    "BlackBoxLevelCard.png"
    ,"FruitLevelCard.png"
    ,"SportsLevelCard.png"
    ,"BarnLevelCard.png"
    ,"SeaLevelCard.png"
    ,"SpaceLevelCard.png"
]

let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

let w10 = screenWidth * 0.10
let w40 = screenWidth  * 0.40
let w50 = screenWidth  * 0.50
let w60 = screenWidth  * 0.60

let h50 = screenHeight  * 0.50

let cardMargin = w10
let cardSize = CGSize(width: w40, height: w60)
let startPosition = CGPoint(x: w50, y: h50)

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let scene = levelSelectionScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    let skView = view as SKView
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    cardNode.zPosition = 100
    self.addChild(cardNode)

for i in 1...levelCardArray.count {

 let currentArrayValue = i - 1

  let cardSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: levelCardArray[currentArrayValue])
  cardSprite.size = cardSize
  cardSprite.position = CGPoint(x: startPosition.x + (CGFloat(currentArrayValue) * (cardSize.width + cardMargin)), y: startPosition.y)
  cardSprite.zPosition = cardNode.zPosition
  cardSprite.name = "levelCardObject"
  cardNode.addChild(cardSprite)

}
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: There is a lot to go over with you,  I would recommend not using the Screen size within SpriteKit,  everything should be done using scene size

Comment: Don't be mean, and demeaning, @Knight0fDragon. This is a direct result of Apple's marketing, poor documentation and multiple levels of active and passive deception and obfuscation. In this particular case, Dave, you're struggling with the discrepancy between the way Apple portrays dealing with their variations in screen sizes and shapes as easy, and the fact that it's not. It's a contrived mess. Once you detangle the way they treat multiple screen sizes and shapes you'll discover just about every other portrayal of ease and simplicity (by Apple) is equally disingenuous and deliberate bullshit.

Comment: That was neither mean or demeaning

Comment: What's strange about this is the acceptance and defence of this kind of abhorrent behaviour (of all tech companies) by their most knowledgeable users, the developers. Because developers have (through experience) learnt to see through (some of) the deceptions and lies, they expect everyone else to see, too. Which is just plain wrongheaded, and self advantageous.

Comment: "There is a lot to go over with you..." this is both.

Comment: I'm not an expert on screen vs scene vs frame, etc. I target iPads and work at a fixed 1024x768, so am not able to differentiate between the supposition he's making that's false (on screen size) vs the correct use of scene width information, and frame, etc. You probably can, and this leads to an answer to this exact problem that's likely simple to articulate, and not a lot. Somewhere (i presume) the scene size is based off the screen size, or some other connection between the virtual and the real. This has probably been covered before, but I don't even know the right terminology to search it.

Comment: "There is a lot to go over with you" is not demeaning, and it is not mean. It means there is a lot of material to discuss, so he needs to be prepared for it.  Stop flooding comments with needless banter.

Comment: I would like to thank both of you Confused and KnightOfDragon. I don't take any offense to it at all, I appreciate the discussion that you are having and I feel like it's pointing me in the right direction to find a better solution which is just what I was looking for :) I'll do some more research on the difference between screen size and scene size and see if I can do some testing with scene size and see if it helps at all. I definitely realize that I have a LONG way to go with best practices and understanding of coding. Just teaching myself as I can on the side :) But the comments do help!

Comment: I went through and adjusted everything to reference SCENE size instead of SCREEN size and tried adjusting the width and height of the scene as well to make it larger and there is zero change in the way that it displays. It is still cutting into exactly the same spot on those nodes. Any other ideas on what I may want to look into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried all day today to try to find a way to make this work through resizing the scenes and views and haven't had any luck with it at all.

My solution is to check for the device type and if it's an iPad I am reducing the image sizes and buffer between images until it doesn't cut them off. I don't consider this a very good solution, really just a work around until I can find a better way to do it. Thank you guys for your thoughts though. I definitely appreciate it!